# How do you get the distribution of a linear combination of the quadratures using the Wigner function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

I know you can get the distribution of a quadrature, x or p, by integrating the Wigner function over all the rest of variables (2N-1 variables for an N mode state). But how do  you get the distribution of let's say $$2x_1+p_2$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.l.o.g., consider two modes, *N*=2, and thus a Wigner distribution function of 4 variables, $W(x_1,x_2,p_1,p_2)$, th remaining ones having been integrated over.

As you suggest, the marginal ***normalized*** distribution of $x_1$ is
$$
f(x_1) = \int\!\! dx_2dp_1 dp_2 ~W ,\qquad  \leadsto \\
\langle g(x_1)\rangle = \int\!\! dx_1 ~g(x_1) f(x_1),
$$
etc,  for any function *g* of quadratures.

You appear to be interested in changing variables, unclear why.  In any case, for $y\equiv 2x_1+p_2$, (so, for unit Jacobean, take
$z=x_1+p_2$), whence
$$
f(y) = \int\!\! dx_2  dp_2 dz~ W , \qquad \leadsto \\
\langle g(y)\rangle = \int\!\! d y~ g( y) f(y),
$$
and so on. Linear quadratures amount to trivial linear transformations of the quadratures.